# jQuery animation callback doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, callback

Why doesn't it fire the alert?

```
var $anchor = $(this);

$('.hide').val($(this).attr('href'));
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'easeInOutCirc'
}, function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple different syntax options you can use with `.animate()`.  When you pass a properties object and an options object (like you are doing), the completion function goes in the options object not as the third parameter like this:

```
var $anchor = $(this);

$('.hide').val($(this).attr('href'));
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
  }, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'easeInOutCirc',
    complete: function () {
        alert('test');
    }
  }
);
```

This is described in full in the [jQuery .animate() doc](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
.animate( properties, options )

properties - A map of CSS properties that the animation will move toward.

options - A map of additional options to pass to the method. Supported keys:
    duration: A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
    easing: A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.
    complete: A function to call once the animation is complete.
    step: A function to be called after each step of the animation.
    queue: A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately. As of jQuery 1.7, the queue option can also accept a string, in which case the animation is added to the queue represented by that string.
    specialEasing: A map of one or more of the CSS properties defined by the properties argument and their corresponding easing functions (added 1.4).
```

Comment: For such a ridiculous question title, this answer is most helpful!

Answer (score 2):

try to specify the third parameter as "complete" like so:

```
var $anchor = $(this);

$('.hide').val($(this).attr('href'));
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'easeInOutCirc'
}, complete: function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: My html is fine and its compiling properly without the function. I get no errors. You error comes because .hide doesn't have any attr.

Comment: ok, I think it is the 'complete' parameter (see updated code above)

Comment: This is not correct.  You can see my answer above for where the `complete:` parameter goes.  It's not a third parameter to the animate function, but a property of the second parameter.

Comment: @jfriend00 -just for my own personal reference.. I modeled my answer after the example directly above "additional notes" here (http://api.jquery.com/animate/)  -would that not work here?

Comment: You missed a detail in that example and yours doesn't follow that.  Yours isn't even legal javascript.  In the jQuery example, the `specialEasing` item is it's own object embedded in the second object which means the `complete:` option in that example is part of the second object unlike in yours.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. @jfriend00's answer saved my day. It's really weird since this answer follow's jQuery's documentation: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @mila - I don't see any jQuery documentation that shows a properties object as an argument, an options object as an argument, followed by a completion function like in this answer.  It simply isn't like this in the doc.  If you use the options object, then you put the complete handler in the options object, not as the third argument.  That's how the jQuery documentation shows it too.